# Docker Image - How can I get the right SHA256(prime, timestamp, nonce) to get the auth token?

Tags: swift, xcode, docker, sha, entropy

I have installed the docker image to hit the APIs. I have started an iOS app where, I have to brute force a prime number between the range of prime numbers that could go to maximum 20 bit number in its binary form.

Now, form an `SHA256(prime_binary_form, timestamp, nonce)` hit an API that checks the SHA256(value) that is a path param and "value" is sent as body in this POST request. If the prime number matches, only then I will get the auth token

The nonce keeps increasing until I get a match with numeric-alpha value `"0123456789abcdef"` with the `SHA256 hash value` that was mined. for example: if the difficulty is 2, then the `SHA256 value` should start with "01" and hence the nonce changes until i get a match.

I am able to get the SHA256 with prime number and a match with the difficulty. But since I have more than 130k prime numbers and difficulty with max 16, How do I use minimal entropy (time and CPU usage) to get the right SHA256 / prime number to hit the API to get the auth token. As simple brute force of prime numbers has hundreds of thousands of calls to the server, which does not seem right.

I was told that since it is a docker image the value is prime number is generated when the application is created.

Can anyone help me with a code snippet? I am currently using Swift on Xcode.